# Trying to deploy a test rails app to Torquebox, keep getting rack errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jboss, torque

So, I've been following the documentation for Torquebox found here:

http://torquebox.org/documentation/1.0.0/

I have the JBOSS stuff working, and deployed a test rails app (empty) to it. I successfully hit the default "Welcome Aboard" rails page.

However, if I try to quickly scaffold out some test code with:

rails g scaffold Demo

and then try to hit /demos, I get a huge error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit
org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter.doRack(RackFilter.java:118)
org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:103)
org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:75)
```

And when I look at the JBOSS/Torquebox logs, I see:

> 10:40:32,367 INFO  [STDOUT] Could not find rack-1.2.1 in any of the sources
>   10:40:32,368 ERROR [org.torquebox.rack.core.servlet.RackFilter] Error invoking Rack filter: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit

I'm a little confused. If I just deploy my rails app normally, with rails s, everything works just fine.

Here is what I remember doing:

- confirmed I have over Java 6
- installed Torquebox from binaries
- set all my path/system variables
- ran the JBOSS server
- created my rails app using the template command provided
- required 'torquebox-rake-support' in my Rakefile (required me to install some gems, as I'm on RVM)
- rake torquebox:deploy  to deploy.

I can see the splash welcome page, like I said, but no routes seem to work.

Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.  I was using rvm, but forgot to start up the jboss server under rvm. Since it was started using the default jruby included, it didn't have the bundle installer to give it rack, and the like.

As an aside, I also tried running everything under the included jruby, and had problems getting the rails gem to install. Turns out it was a problem with the latest version of arel? Installing it separately (and first) at a lower version worked fine.